# C# Coded UI testing - enter text into a javascript window.prompt text box

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I'm running coded UI tests in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017.

My webpage under test has a javascript popup asking for an e-mail address to be entered. I can locate the confirmationPopup (highlight is drawn correctly), and I can click buttons within it, such as the cancel.

```
confirmationPopup = new WinWindow();
confirmationPopup.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlType, "Dialog");
confirmationPopup.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "#32770");
confirmationPopup.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
confirmationPopup.Find();
confirmationPopup.DrawHighlight();

var cancelButton = new WinButton(confirmationPopup);
cancelButton.SearchProperties.Add(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name, "Cancel");
Mouse.Click(cancelButton);
```

What I am struggling to do is enter text in the popup's input box:

```
var textInput = new WinEdit(confirmationPopup);
textInput.SearchProperties.Add(WinEdit.PropertyNames.ClassName, "Edit");
textInput.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
textInput.DrawHighlight();
textInput.Text = "bill@microsoft.com";
```

The highlight is drawn around the correct control, but the textInput.Text= line gives an error 
***Additional information: SetProperty of "Text" is not supported on control type: Window***

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure the code you posted is what is running?  The error indicates that the control type is wrong.  You should not need to add search properties for the class name, it would be part of the WinEdit definition.  You shouldn't need to specify TechnologyName either.  In the DrawHighlight call, is it highlighting the text area or the whole confirmation popup?

Comment: I'm new to this, so yes this is the code running, but I fully accept it may neither be good nor necessary code. The drawhighlight is just around the text area. If I do confirmationPopup.DrawHighlight() then that encircles the whole confirmation popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of interacting with javascript prompt window.

```
// go to a public site which has a prompt
var window = BrowserWindow.Launch("http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/alert2.shtml");

var contentDiv = new HtmlDiv(window);
contentDiv.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id, "contentcolumn", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);

var promptButton = new HtmlInputButton(contentDiv);
promptButton.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlInputButton.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition, "name=\"B4\"", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);

promptButton.SetFocus();
Keyboard.SendKeys("{ENTER}");

// now the prompt is showing, find it and set text
var promptWindow = new WinWindow();
promptWindow.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlType, "Dialog");
promptWindow.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "#32770");

promptWindow.DrawHighlight();

var middleWindow = new WinWindow(promptWindow);
middleWindow.DrawHighlight();

var inputBox = new WinEdit(middleWindow);
inputBox.DrawHighlight();
inputBox.Text = "Hello world!";
```

When using the inspect feature of coded ui, I see there is a middle window.  Using it or not, I am able to find the edit.

[image: 2 Windows]

Comment: Interesing that there is a 'middle window'. I'll try that approach and report back. - thanks

Comment: Solved, thank you. The issue was there was a 'hidden' (aka didn't look hard enough), window within the window and the text input was within that